# Wildcards in JSONB

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Looking for a wildcard operator to query JSONB data types. For example with this:

```
$> Campaign.find(43).style_item_map

{"0"=>{"items"=>[876, 875], "style"=>"First", "featured"=>[876, 875]}, "1"=>{"items"=>[999, 998], "style"=>"Secondary",
"featured"=>[]}}
```

Looking for a query like this: (% doesn't work here)

```
Campaign.where("style_item_map @> '{\"%\":{\"items\": [876]}}'")
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to use [**`jsonb_each`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) twice for this kind of document:

```
WITH t(style_item_map) AS ( VALUES
  ('{
  "0": {
    "items":[876, 875],
    "style":"First",
    "featured":[876, 875]
  },
  "1": {
    "items":[999, 998],
    "style":"Secondary",
   "featured":[]
   }
}'::JSONB)
)
SELECT
  item.key,
  inner_item
FROM t,
    jsonb_each(t.style_item_map) item,
    jsonb_each(item.value) inner_item
WHERE
  inner_item.key = 'items'
AND
  inner_item.value @> '[876]';
```

Result:

```
 key |      inner_item      
-----+----------------------
 0   | (items,"[876, 875]")
(1 row)
```